# Using custom dialog box in custom listview button click

Tags: android

I am working on an android project where I have to fetch data from server and display it in a custom listview along with a button, I have fetched and showed the listview but I want to start a dialog box whenever the button in the each row of the listview is clicked. I am stucked on how to initiate the call from the button press, I have tried in some ways but doesn't work.. My codes are pasted below, any help would be greatly appreciated..

The contactAdapter class of my code is given below:

```
package com.example.sohan.doctor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by Sohan on 6/9/2016.
 */
public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contacts> {
   // notification nt = new notification();
    List<Contacts> list = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
    View row;
    ContactHolder contactHolder;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View v;
    private Activity activity;

    public ContactAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }



    public void add(List<Contacts> updatedList) {
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(updatedList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public Contacts getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        row = convertView;

        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_symptom_layout,parent,false);
            contactHolder = new ContactHolder();
            contactHolder.Name =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            contactHolder.Age =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            contactHolder.Height =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            contactHolder.Weight =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            contactHolder.Symptom =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
            contactHolder.button = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button3);
            contactHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {               // this is the onClick method for the custom button
                    String name;
//                    name = list.get(position).getName();
//                    Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), name+" is served ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), "Position of "+name+" is "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      callDialog cd = new callDialog();
                      cd.showBox();
                      //android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = cd.getSupportFragmentManager();
                      //md.show(, "my_dialog");

                    //---------  another solution
//                    inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
//                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialogbox, null);
//                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
//                    builder.setView(v).setPositiveButton("Send Treatment", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//                        @Override
//                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//
//                        }
//                    });
//                    builder.show();
                    //---------- another solution
                }
            });

            row.setTag(contactHolder);
        }
        else{

            contactHolder = (ContactHolder)row.getTag();
        }



        Contacts contacts = (Contacts)this.getItem(position);
        contactHolder.Name.setText("Name: "+contacts.getName());
        contactHolder.Age.setText("Age: "+contacts.getAge());
        contactHolder.Height.setText("Height: "+contacts.getHeight());
        contactHolder.Weight.setText("Weight: "+contacts.getWeight());
        contactHolder.Symptom.setText("Symptoms: " + contacts.getSymptom());
        return row;

    }

    public Activity getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

    static class ContactHolder{
        TextView Name;
        TextView Age;
        TextView Height;
        TextView Weight;
        TextView Symptom;
        Button button;
    }


          class callDialog extends FragmentActivity {

            public void showBox(){
                MyDialog md = new MyDialog();
                md.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "my_dialog_box");
            }
        }



}
```

The dialog box code are given below:

```
package com.example.sohan.doctor;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by Sohan on 7/13/2016.
 */
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View v;
    public Dialog  onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialogbox, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(v).setPositiveButton("Send Treatment", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the code in your adapter class? Isn't that working?

Comment: The app crashes when contactHolder.button is pressed, rest of the things are working, all the other data's are displayed along with the button perfectly.

Comment: Post your crash log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an Example of how to create Custom Dialog

```
 public void showCustomDialog() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inf.inflate(R.layout.email_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    final EditText et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.id_student_email_edittext);
    final EditText nameEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.id_student_name_edittext);
    final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.student_gender_group);
    final RadioButton radiomale = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.gender_male);
    final RadioButton radioFemale = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.gender_female);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            //Click listner
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            //click listner.
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

and this is the layout file for custom dialog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dip">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id_student_name_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id_student_email_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:id="@+id/student_gender_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/gender_male"
        android:text="Male"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gender_female"
        android:text="Female"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Just call that method in onItemClick of listview

Customize the layout however you want and access elements as i showed in java code

Comment: Thnx it worked, :-) it will be getContext().getSystemService(.......)..

Comment: That's  because i was in Activity class 
if you are in Fragment you might have to use getActivity()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Customize the alert as you need.

```
contactHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) { 
AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());
    alertbox.setMessage("Message");
    alertbox.setTitle("Title");
    alertbox.setIcon(R.drawable.img);

    alertbox.setPositiveButton("Send Treatment",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                        int arg1) {

                }
            });
  alertbox.show();
  }
            });
```

Comment: This works but I have a custom dialog box, how can I use it?? Your above solution pops a window just, I need some edit text and text views in the alertbox..

Answer (score 0):

```
   mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                showDialog();
            }
        });


private void showDialog()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
        builder.setTitle("No Connection");
        builder.setMessage("check your internet connection");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
               //do it here
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

You can use listview item click event .and show it pop.

Answer (score 0):

```
callDialog cd = new callDialog();
```

Do not create a FragmentActivity with new.

Use an Intent.